# Virtualbox failed to install?

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, virtualization

I have recently downloaded Virtualbox 5, and I ran the .deb file I obtained from the website. I try to use MS-DOS 6.22 and it comes up with the error message.

```
 '[RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)

 The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of 
 VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not 
 successful. Executing

 '/sbin/rcvboxdrv setup'

 may correct this. Make sure that you do not mix the OSE version and 
 the PUEL version of VirtualBox.

 where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime what: 4 
 VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support 
 driver doesn't match the version of the user. ]'
```

I even tried to run the suggested command, and it failed.

Answer (score 7):

The only thing that helped me was uninstalling `virtualbox-dkms` since that package was in an older version:

```
sudo dpkg -P virtualbox-dkms
```

Then I reinstalled `virtualbox` and it worked.

Comment: Helped for me, too (on updating from 5.2 to 6.0)

Comment: This is done by `sudo apt-get autoremove` as recommended by [Bevor's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/984921).

Comment: I had installed 6.1.4 but then  by mistake installed the extension pack via the repo instead of downloading as the repo version is for 5.x.  It removed 6.14 and installed 5.x.  After realizing this and re-installing 6.1.4 I ran into this issue which was caused by this dkms package and fixed per this post.

Answer (score 6):

Run:

```
sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
sudo apt -f install
```

And if that dosen't work:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Comment: Many thanks for this - solved the issue for me after upgrading Ubuntu Trusty's distro-provided 4.x vbox package to a 5.1 package from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I wanted to install the latest version from the website, but I had an outdated Virtualbox repository version installed (by the package manager). That's why I still had some kernel modules running which were not deleted while uninstalling process. I solved it by:

```
apt-get remove virtualbox
apt-get autoremove [absolutely needed to remove the old kernel modules]
/sbin/vboxconfig [after you install the version from the website with dpkg -i]
```

Btw: Basically you should't bypass the package manager, but I couldn't run VMs and wanted to figure out if the problem exists in the latest version.

Comment: Worked for me (after moving from 5.0 to 5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04)   [link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/virtualbox-reached-5-2-major-release-how-to-install/). All is well now.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do would be to install the version of Virtualbox that is included in the Ubuntu software repositories. In general, this is preferred over installing a downloaded version (unless you need special features that the version in the software repos doesn't offer). The version of Virtualbox in the Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) repos is 5.0.18-1.

First, uninstall the version of Virtualbox you downloaded.

Then open a terminal (Alt-Ctrl-T) and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked for me when trying to run a Virtual Machine, I uninstalled version 5.1 and run the command and it loaded the Virtual Machine perfectly.

Comment: Same here.  Wasn't working on repo versions; had to install 5.1 to get my VM to start.  Next time I started the computer, VM refused to start.  Returning to Repo version fixed the problem, at least for now...  :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too. Then I found a correct way to delete old version of VirtualBox.

```
$ sudo /opt/VirtualBox/uninstall.sh
$ sudo rm -rf /opt/VirtualBox/
```

Then install VirtualBox again. It worked for me.